# Mac OS xargs command unpredictable behaviour

Tags: bash, macos, docker, xargs

I am really confused with xargs behaviour running on Mac OS

I have image like:

```
docker images | grep "docregistry/"
docregistry/jackrabbit   latest
```

I want to remove it by a filter like:

```
docker images | grep "docregistry/" | awk '{print $1":"$2}' | xargs -0 docker rmi -f
```

But I got an error:

```
Error: No such image: docregistry/jackrabbit:latest
```

If I run `docker rmi docregistry/jackrabbit` everything works as expected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest to remove `-0`.

Answer (score 2):

`-0` tells `xargs` that it should split its input into arguments for the `docker` command on null characters, but your pipeline doesn't *prodcue* any null characters. That means the newline that `awk` outputs is treated as *part* of the image name; the error is really telling you that the image `docregistry/jackrabbit:latest\n` does not exist. (The error would probably be more obvious if `grep` output more than one image name.)

Assuming that Docker images cannot (or, at least in this case, will not) contain whitespace, just drop the `-0` from the `xargs` command.